# How to keep n processes running on a list of jobs that vary in length in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing, batch-processing, jobs

so a little background on what I am trying to do: Below I have written some code that will create jobs in batches of 4 and run them. These jobs involve a lot of data so I want to limit how many are running at once. Based on the contents of the data these jobs can vary in execution time from about 2 - 15 mins. Below I have written code to run these jobs in batches of 4. This much is working.

[Current Code execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRU3Q.png)

[Desired Code execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG4UG.png)

Again, these jobs vary greatly in how long they take to run. So this makes it seems like running jobs in batches of 4 (or n) could result in time wasted. For example given 4 jobs if 3 take 2 minutes and the other takes 10 then there will be 8 minutes of only one process running.

So my question: Is there a way to supply a list of jobs to some function/class/whatever so that I can keep the number of processes and jobs running constant?

```
        manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        return_dict = manager.dict()

        jobs = []

        numOFProc = 4

        for api in WellAPIs: #iterate over individual wells in a file

            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.processWell, args=(df,CreatingPrediction,cache,df, newColList, clustringPredictionColName,return_dict,lock))
            jobs.append(p)

            p.start()

            numOfActiveProc = len(jobs)

            if numOFProc <= numOfActiveProc:
                for proc in jobs:
                    proc.join()
                jobs = []
            print "jobs: " + str(jobs)


        for proc in jobs:
            proc.join()
        jobs = []

        for parDF in return_dict.values():
            outDf = outDf.append(parDF)
```

Comment: Hello @SamiWood. Your code seems (too?) long, could you extract only the important parts and remove the rest, to make it more easy to understand what the problem is?

Comment: `from threading import enumerate as t_enumerate` and then do `while len(t_enumerate()) > 1: print('Still got threads running')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)   # NUMBER OF PROCESSES
    print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))   # APPLIES `f` TO EACH ELEMENT
    # APPEND THIS TO MY TODO LIST AND PRINT IT WHEN IT'S DONE
    p.apply_async(f, (10,), callback=print)
    print(p.apply_async(f, (10,)).get())
```

You can do a `Pool(4)`, then use `map` with any iterable, when the iterable is consumed, the function stops. Alternatively, you can use apply async, which uses either a callback or `.get()`

Comment: Thanks for the response. This seems promising however now if I have a list of say 10 jobs then this will kick of all 10 jobs distributed across 4 processes. What I am wanting to do is run 4 jobs each job as a process while keeping the pipeline full. The reason I want to limit the number of jobs is that each one needs several GB of ram so 10 is too much.

Comment: Ok thanks I think I got it working. I had to write a helper method that checked If PIDs of created processes still existed, sleeping if there were 4 pids, or continuing to consume jobs from callback if there were less. Feels like I still made it a bit more complicated than it needed to be but if it works it works. Thanks Again :)

Comment: No problem, while callbacks are uncommon in python, they are useful for some tasks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a pool. The `multiprocessing` package has an implementation that you can use. Please refer to the official documentation for details on its usage.